# how to set a particular song for alarm in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, alarm

I am developing task reminder kind of chrome extension.For this I want to set a song from hard disk which will play on alarm time is over.Please explain how to code this.[sorry for bad English]

thanks in advance.

Comment: post what you tried, what fails, what the console says and your manifest.

Comment: Please provide more code, especially you `manifest.json`, logic code and your error info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your song is in your extension folder:

```
var mySong = new Audio("audio.mp3");
mySong.play();
```

Assuming you're creating a notification, you can play this song like this in a callback function:

```
var myNotification = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Hello!",
    message: "This is a notification with an audio"
};
chrome.notifications.create("myNotificationID", myNotification, function() {
    var mySong = new Audio("audio.mp3");
    mySong.play()
})
```

Comment: No, song is not playing but notification is fine. Do we have to add any new permission in manifest file to access data in hard disk? Please help me

Comment: Is it a content script or a background page? It works fine for me from background page. You can create one and send a message from your content script. Detailed about messaging between your content script and background page here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: thanks its working for single song(preset default song) but I was trying to choose a song from the user then setting the path using  mySong.src ="path"  . Its not giving any error message in console and song is not played. I tried alerting the path it shows C:/fakepath/song.mp3. I couldn't able to get the path.